# i try to run a python file using streamlit, it gives me an error saying saying streamlit is not a pacakge, i did installl streamlit

Tags: python

it my first time using **streamlit**, i have installed sreamlit using `pip install streamlit` which it installed. itry running a python file using `streamlit run pop.py` it gives me this error below :

```
C:\Users\DELL>streamlit run pop.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\streamlit.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'streamlit.cli'; 'streamlit' is not a package
```

i don't know what to do. please help

Answer (score 1):

You are using it in Python. After opening the cmd, do not write `python`. Just go to the folder and write `streamlit run pop.py` in cmd. Not in Python.